# My own bundle doen't want to start, because it can't import log4j

Tags: java, osgi, openhab

I've created my own binding for OpenHab2, build it with `mvn clean package` and uploaded it to `/usr/share/openhab2/addons/`.

My problem is that bundle is not starting. In logs there are this warns:

> 2016-11-25 10:55:00.518 [WARN ] [org.apache.felix.fileinstall        ] - Error while starting bundle: file:/usr/share/openhab2/addons/org.openhab.binding.rf24-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.openhab.binding.rf24 [189]
>     Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.log4j; version="1.2.17"
>
> ```
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)[org.eclipse.osgi-3.10.2.v20150203-1939.jar:]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:393)[org.eclipse.osgi-3.10.2.v20150203-1939.jar:]
>     at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1245)[8:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
>     at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1217)[8:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
>     at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startAllBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1207)[8:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
>     at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:504)[8:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
>     at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:358)[8:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
>     at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:310)[8:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
> ```
>
> 2016-11-25 10:55:00.536 [WARN ] [org.apache.felix.fileinstall        ] - Error while starting bundle: file:/usr/share/openhab2/addons/org.openhab.binding.rf24-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.openhab.binding.rf24 [189]
>     Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.log4j; version="1.2.17"
>
> ```
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)[org.eclipse.osgi-3.10.2.v20150203-1939.jar:]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:393)[org.eclipse.osgi-3.10.2.v20150203-1939.jar:]
>     at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1245)[8:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
>     at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1217)[8:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
>     at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:509)[8:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
>     at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:358)[8:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
>     at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:310)[8:org.apache.felix.fileinstall:3.5.0]
> ```
>
> 2016-11-25 11:00:16.306 [ERROR] [org.openhab.binding.rf24            ] - FrameworkEvent ERROR - org.openhab.binding.rf24
>   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.openhab.binding.rf24 [189]
>     Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.log4j; version="1.2.17"
>
> ```
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)[org.eclipse.osgi-3.10.2.v20150203-1939.jar:]
>     at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)[org.eclipse.osgi-3.10.2.v20150203-1939.jar:]
> ```

Installed on RPi3 Raspbian via http://docs.openhab.org/installation/linux.html

Comment: The message is very clear: it asks for log4j; which doesn't seem to be there.  So did you try providing that as well?

Comment: I tried to put log4j jar in the same dir that bundle is but this didn't worked

Comment: "This didn't work" is a useless comment. What actually happened? How did that differ from what you expected to happen? Was there an error message? Etc...

Comment: I still have the same message. Nothing changed